# a dialog for throublshooting instead of print command pyqt

Tags: c++, python, utf-8, qt4, pyqt

I have a `code` and inherited from a `Qt class`, So :

```
print mystr.encode("utf-8")
```

give me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

So, I decided to use `Qt ready dialog`, because i know it have same `dialog` for `throublshooting` such as `alert` in `JavaScript`, My coworker was using in `C++` same thing.

**Question:** Which is name of their `function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QMessageBox.information(...)
```

Api reference for it-
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmessagebox.html#information

Comment: Also, you need to cast mystr which is a QString to python string to use the encode method